# Display ListBox by 2 branches in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a listbox to display a datasource. The datasource has only one field ("ClassName"). 
I want the listbox is displayed by 2 branches.

Example:

ClassName:

ClassName1

ClassName2

ClassName3

ClassName4

Display:      =>

ClassName1    ClassName2 
ClassName3    ClassName4

Just tell me how to do that please!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change the Listbox's ItemsPanel to something that supports the display that you want.  The WrapPanel would probably work well, but you'd have to use a custom listboxitem style to ensure the width is the same for all items.  You could also use a Grid with 2 columns.  You'd have to specify the Column each item is in however, which might be tricky.